# I can't scrape elements present in the HTML page source in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I inspected the HTML page source of the webpage, the elements are there, but when I try to scrape it it's not showing up. The code did not throw a missing element error but it simply returned a null.

I read online saying that I have to switch iframes etc. but I could not find any iframes wrapping the element I intend to scrape.

I am using a headless browser but I changed the user agent to fool the website into thinking it's non-headless.

Here is the URL to the webpage I'm trying to scrape. It is a Russian website: https://www.mvideo.ru/products/lazernoe-mfu-hp-neverstop-laser-1200w-4ry26a-30044796

And this is the user agent I set:
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36

```
def getAdLinks(url):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > mvid-root > mvid-modal-container-old > mvid-modal-old > div > div > div > mvid-icon').click()
    sleep(1)
    #frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="iframe_flock_data_provider"]')
    #driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#PRODUCTS_TO_COMPARE_BLOCK_ID')))
    links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('mvideo-product-card-compare')
    """def condition(element):
        return '/products' in element.get_attribute('href')
    filtered = list(filter(condition, links))"""
    print(len(links))
```

That's the code I have. I am trying to scrape the links to the recommended/similar products section of the page.

[This is the screenshot of the part of the webpage I want to scrape. I've outlined the part in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc8xU.png)

Comment: please share your python code and error

Comment: There are 15 iframe on that page, pls share your code and which part did not work ?

Comment: I put in the code in there. I pass the URL to the function parameter. I use Google Chrome to visit the page.

Answer (score 0):

In case of this website, you'll have to scroll to that particular section for the elements to load.
You can use move_to_element() method to move to a particular area on the page and then wait for the elements to load.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#PRODUCTS_TO_COMPARE_BLOCK_ID')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
```

You can find the complete function code below:-

```
def getAdLinks(url):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > mvid-root > mvid-modal-container-old > mvid-modal-old > div > div > div > mvid-icon').click()
    sleep(1)
    element=WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#PRODUCTS_TO_COMPARE_BLOCK_ID')))
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform() #move to the required section 
    sleep(10)#wait for the elements to load.
    links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('mvideo-product-card-compare')
    print(len(links))
```